# estudo de wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Alguém pode me ajudar, o que esse comando faz?

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src = '', $deps = array, $ver = false, $media = 'all' )
```

Eu sei  que ele é um `hook` , mas queria entender o que cada parte dele faz.

Comment: Complementando a resposta abaixo: O `$deps` é para informar as dependências. Ex.: O componente `ekko-lightbox` depende do `Bootstrap`, isso fará com que o *WordPress* carregue primeiro a dependência e depois o dependente; O `$ver` serve para informar a versão do arquivo, caso preencha esse campo, o *WordPress* irá adicionar o parâmetro `?ver=<versão>` na URL; O `$media` serve para informar se o *CSS* é para impressão, tela ou ambos (ou informar *media query*, ex: `(orientation: landscape)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chama uma página de estilo ao tema

Primeiro parâmetro (`$handle`): Adiciona um nome à folha de estilo. *Obs:* Se vc precisar fazer duas chamadas de arquivos *.css*, você deve adicionar obrigatoriamente dois nomes distintos, um para cada folha.

Segundo parâmetro (`$src`): O caminho da sua folha de estilo. *Obs:* A URL deve ser absoluta

Exemplo de chamada (adicionar no arquivo `functions.php`):

```
function _theme_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( '_theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.min.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_theme_assets' );
```